# How do I calculate the total when a specific column equals something?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets I have the following setup:

```
------------------------------------------------
| Game        | Player 1 | Player 2 | Player 3 |
------------------------------------------------
| Racing      | L        | W        | X        |
| Sonic 2     | W        | L        | X        |
| Sonic 2     | W        | X        | L        |       
| Sonic 2     | L        | X        | W        |
| Racing      | L        | W        | X        |
| Racing      | L        | W        | X        |
------------------------------------------------
```

Each "game" is a two player game.

- **W** represents a win
- **L** represents a loss
- **X** represents did not play

I want to calculate the following and output it to cells:

1. Total wins at game "Racing" for player 1.
2. Total losses at game "Racing" for player 1.
3. Wins at game "Racing" for player 1 while playing against player 2.
4. Losses at game "Racing" for player 1 while playing against player 2.
5. Wins at game "Racing" for player 1 while playing against player 3.
6. Losses at game "Racing" for player 1 while playing against player 3.

   etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into using the SUMIF function.  You can set up a function to take the sum's a column's cell has a specific value.  With this, you can also embed additional if statements.
That is what I would use if using excel.

I haven't used this function in google docs, but if its not supported yet, then try the below link that mentions it.
[SUMIF work around](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ag79AuCg7-_tdHNHeWgzWG5yZTROcXlYTVRsdkNld3c&hl=en#gid=7)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to [SUMIFS function in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128987/179529)

Basically you want something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(((Games!$A:$A)=$A2) * ((Games!$B:$B)='W') * (1) ))
```

Where `Games` is the sheet with your game information and `$A2` is the cell with the values as  *Racing*, *Sonic 2* etc.