# Filter a range by array

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet containing the teams of the UEFA EURO 2012, and their scores:

```
Team     Points  Goals scored
------   ------  ------------
Germany    6          3
Croatia    3          3
Ireland    0          1
...       ...        ...
```

Now I want to filter that list, so that the result contains only a subset of the teams involved. Specifically, I want the resulting list to contain only the teams *Germany, Netherlands, Portugal, Italy, England, France, Spain* and *Croatia*.

I know I can use the `FILTER` function to extract a single value from the table. Thus, I could probably write a `FILTER` expression like `=FILTER(A2:C; A2:A = 'Germany' OR A2:A = 'Netherlands' OR A2:A = 'Portugal' OR ...)` but I would like to avoid this, as the list of teams is sort of dynamic.

So the question is: How can I filter the table by a **range** of values - not just a single value?

Comment: Check out a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128987/179529

Answer (score 71, accepted):

For answer-seekers who stumble onto this thread as I did, see this [Google product forum page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/filter$20by$20range$20of$20values/docs/C3oSqDDTrQU/_7ity_vKESAJ), where both Yogi and ahab present solutions to the question of how to filter a range of data by another range of data.

If `A3:C` contains the range of UEFA EURO 2012 data to be filtered, and `D3:D` contains the list of teams by which to filter, then `E3` ...

```
=FILTER(A3:C, MATCH(A3:A, D3:D,0))
```

or

```
=FILTER(A3:C, COUNTIF(D3:D, A3:A))
```

[image: Positive filter results]

Conversely, if you'd like to filter by teams **not** listed in `D3:D`, then `E3`...

```
=FILTER(A3:C, ISNA(MATCH(A3:A, D3:D,0)))
```

or

```
=FILTER(A3:C, NOT(COUNTIF(D3:D, A3:A)))
```

[image: Negative filter results]

Here's an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14GTYCP1n9iiFnFmNSrXVCPjnAMAm5o8JCJsbPvRzuGc/edit?usp=sharing) I've made to demonstrate these functions' effectiveness.

Comment: I would like to note, that you should include the actual details in your answer, as links can often be broken, making this answer not so useful in the future.

Comment: Thank you, Douglas. You're absolutely right. I hope my updated answer will suffice.

Answer (score 5):

#### for those who need to use [greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4005713/greg) formulas and struggle with range mismatch of `FILTER`

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0))

=FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A))

=FILTER(A1:A, ISNA(MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))

=FILTER(A1:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)))
```

in case you need to use `FILTER` formula to return evaluation between two ranges, and those two ranges are of different size (like when they are returned from a query) and can't be altered to match the same size and you just got `FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: etc.` error, then this is a workaround:

to keep it simple let's say your ranges for the filter are **A1:A10** and **B1:B8**, you can use array brackets `{}` to append two virtual rows on range `B1:B8` to match size `A1:A10` by using `REPT`where number of needed repetitions shall be calculated by a simple calculation between initial ranges.

then to this `REPT` formula, we need to add +1 as a correction/failsafe (in a case the difference between two initial ranges is 1), because `REPT` works with a minimum of 2 repetitions. so in a sense, we will need to create a range of `B1:B11` (from `B1:B8`) and laters we will just trim off the last row from a range so it would be `B1:B10` against `A1:A10`. we will use 2 unique symbols for `REPT`

next step would be to wrap `REPT` into `SPLIT` and divide by 2nd unique symbol. then, (based on a further need) this `SPLIT` needs to be wrapped into `TRANSPOSE` (because we want to match column size to column size) and the last step would be to wrap it into `QUERY` and `limit` out the output again by simple math of `COUNTA(A1:A10)` to trim off the last rept. put together it would look like this:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10, NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({B1:B8; 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(A1:A10)-COUNTA(B1:B8)+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(A1:A10), 0), A1:A10)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some possible and different approaches:

`=FILTER(C5:C;REGEXMATCH(C5:C;"one|two|five"))`

result: any text containing one, two, five. Case sensitive.

`=FILTER(C5:C;REGEXMATCH(C5:C;JOIN("|";DC5:DC7)))`

same as previous but values are in list: DC5:DC7

`=FILTER(C5:C;REGEXMATCH(C5:C;"^("&JOIN("|";EE5:EE7)&")$"))`

same as previous + match whole text

---

Suggested earlier options:

`=FILTER(C5:C;MATCH(C5:C;EG5:EG7;))`

`=FILTER(C5:C;countif(EK5:EK7;C5:C))`

Case insensitive result.

Same, not in list

`=FILTER(C5:C;ISNA(MATCH(C5:C;EF5:EF7;)))`

Interesting: gives the difference between lists.

Answer (score 0):

**This is player0 improved answer for when you need to use mismatched table sizes**

The formula filters a whole table based on the list in another column. I used a lambda function so you can easily just change the last three parameters to check if this will work for you.

**argument 1st** - a range of a table to be filtered (or a query result etc.)

**argument 2nd** - column number in the filtered table to check the matching list against

**argument 3rd** - the list of the things the specified column should contain

```
=lambda(table_to_filter, no_of_col_to_filter_by, list_to_match, FILTER(table_to_filter, COUNTIF(QUERY({list_to_match; 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(index(table_to_filter,,no_of_col_to_filter_by))-COUNTA(list_to_match)+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(index(table_to_filter,,no_of_col_to_filter_by)), 0), index(table_to_filter,,no_of_col_to_filter_by))))(A1:C8, 1, G1:G)
```