# How to filter one list of items from another list of items?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a huge list of items in Column A (1,000 items) and a smaller list of items in Column B (510 items).

I want to put a formula in Column C to show only the Column A items not in Column B.

How to achieve this through a formula, preferably a FILTER formula?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Select the list in column A
2. Right-Click and select Name a Range...
3. Enter "ColumnToSearch"
4. Click cell C1
5. Enter this formula: `=MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)`
6. Drag the formula down for all items in B

If the formula fails to find a match, it will be marked "#N/A", otherwise it will be a number.

If you'd like it to be TRUE for match and FALSE for no match, use this formula instead:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0))
```

If you'd like to return the unfound value and return empty string for found values

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,ColumnToSearch,0)),"",B1)
```

Comment: Would like to add that i got the answer from another source :

=filter(A1:A, isna(match(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))

It also solved the problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @Ben! and sorry for the overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method is simply =

```
FILTER(A1:A,if(COUNTIF(B1:B,A1:A),0,1))
```

It's much more efficient.
It uses `countif` to get a 0 or a 1 as an array if the values in B are in A, then it reverses the 0 and 1 to get the values that are missing instead of only the values that are in there. It then filters based on that.
Columns look like this

```
A   B
1   2
2   5
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

ARE formulae:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0))

=FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A))
```

ARE NOT formulae:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, ISNA(MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))

=FILTER(A1:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)))
```

in your case:

```
=FILTER(A1:A; ISNA(MATCH(A:A; B:B; )))
```

[image]

if you face a mismatch of ranges see: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795616/5632629**