# How can I have Google Sheets Query output which values in one list are not present in another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm combining multiple reference lists in google sheets into one master list. Currently, I have a reference list ("Site List") with a column full of location names. I also have the master list ("Master"), where I copy those location names down, and then start inputting the additional data against them.

What I'm trying to achieve is using google sheets query to keep track of which rows in "Site List" have not yet been entered into "Master".

So as soon as something is copied across into the location column in "Master", it will disappear from the list produced by the query. I intend to use this to keep track of which locations I still need to enter on the "Master" sheet.

The formula I've tried so far is:

`=query('Site List'!A1:F,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F where F contains 'Active' and A <> '' and not A matches '"&Textjoin("|",TRUE,Master!A1:A)&"' order by A",1)`

I was anticipating that it would result in a list of all locations in 'Site List' which were not present in 'Master', however, because 'matches' functions using regex, any location name containing parentheses was not filtered out and is still present in the final list, despite already having been entered in 'Master'.

I'm not sure if there's a way around 'matches' failing to filter out values containing parentheses, or if there's another way of doing it that I've not thought of yet.

[Link to sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/171xoRvDwb87C895W8phxFx_eTjZq7Z_c-fyohQbhLKg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share an example?  This will make it easier for others to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter one list of items from another list of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367412/how-to-filter-one-list-of-items-from-another-list-of-items)

Comment: Please enter the expected output (manually) in your test sheet so as for us to get a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to this question is described in [how do I find the values that are in one column but not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606189/1330560), with a little extra to display the extra columns from "Site List"

**Sheet: Remaining Locations**

- Cell A2: `=FILTER('Site List'!A2:A, ISNA(MATCH('Site List'!A2:A,Master!A2:A, 0)))`
- Cell B2: `=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,'Site List'!A1:F,{2,3,4,5,6},0),))`
- Note Row#1 headers are manual text

---

**Remaining**

[image: remaining]

**Site list**

[image: sitelist]