# criterium range broadcasting along sum range in `SUMIF`

Tags: google-sheets

Can Google spreadsheets broadcast rows or columns in their functions, in particular in `SUMIF`, if different range dimensions are used for two arguments?

For example, I was hoping `SUMIF(B1:F1, "Offices", B2:F4)` would return `56+23+23`, because the `1x5` range `B1:F1` would be repeated in the row dimension to match the `3x5` range `B2:F4`. PS: this repeating is called *dimension broadcasting*. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, `SUMIF` just ignores the 2 rows it has no criteria for and returns `56`.

```
     A       B            D        D     E          F
1    Month   Maintenance  Offices  Cars  Employees  Cars 
2    Jan     23           56       43    23         56
3    Feb     12           23       67    43         21
4    March   44           23       45    56         45
```

**Question:** Can I specify a criterium in SUMIF where the column or row stays fixed, as is possible with conditional formatting? Differently put, how can one specify a criterium in SUMIF such that the criterium range is broadcasted?

**Why DSUM does not work**: Notice that `SUMIF(B1:F4,"Offices",B1:F4)` could do the trick, only that it would fail here since the `B1:F4` isn't a proper database since there are two columns named `"Car"`. Moreover, `DSUM` requires the column headers to be adjacent to their data, while I would imagine I'd want to place the total sums between the header and the data. That being said, I also want to learn an imho powerful concept, not the `DSUM` function.

**Conditional formatting** Google spreadsheet does offer broadcasting in formatting, for example, if I format the range `A1:F4` on the condition `=A$1="Cars"`, then the two "Cars" columns would be formatted, even though they are columns `D` and `F`.

**Comparison with numpy, which does broadcasting** `numpy`, Which can be used as a spreadsheet library when programming Python, does something called (dimension) broadcasting. Consider an array (read spreadsheet) `a` of 1 row and 3 columns and another array `b` of 3 rows and 3 columns. We could then ask `numpy` to multiply both element- (read cell-) wise, and it will repeat the single row of `a` three times to match the dimension of `b`:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2]
])

b = numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [7, 8, 9],
])

a * b
```

Outcome, notice that the entire first column is multiplied with 0, the entire second with 1 and the entire third with 2:

```
numpy.array([
    [0, 1, 4],
    [0, 4, 10],
    [0, 8, 18],
])
```

Comment: I failed to see your question

Comment: @player0 The question is whether there is some syntax like `REPEATROWS(A1:F1)` which makes `A1:F1` act as if it is a `n x 6` range instead of a `1 x 6` range depending on the number of rows of a second argument. This principle is called broadcasting, where one dimension (e.g. rows or columns) is repeated to match the same dimension of a different argument, and is a very common feature of libraries dealing with (numerical) tensors (or tables).

Comment: there is a way how to deal with two arrays of different sizes when it's not allowed to have different sizes, using REPT just to match the bigger array so it would pass in formula that requires same sized arrays (like filter for example) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795616/5632629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:F10), "where Col1 = 'Offices'"))
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution, but it doesn't provide syntax to use broadcasting in a generic way, which is what I am looking for. Broadcasting might not be supported by Google spreadsheet, or even be against the spreadsheet methodology, but I'll wait a bit before accepting, while hoping it is supported.