# What is the function for filtering data that is not in a list in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I haven't made a spreadsheet with slightly more advanced formulas for over a year.
I've been trying to do this for hours, searching the internet. But I haven't found anything that works as I need it. it should be simple, but I need help.

I have 3 tables:

1. **requisitions** (responses arriving from a form)
2. **completed** (requisitions completed)
3. **pendencies** I would like this spreadsheet to list all the requisitions data that are in the table: **requisitions**, but that are not yet in the table: **completed**.

spreadsheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EhQllVUSaxAMaLYAfzEa9loHWsEtluO4zIblA03Yxo/edit?usp=sharing

Note: All my requests have a sequential ID in **column A**. It would be just a comparison de ids, bringing the data as the functions: query, filter for example.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I added the spreadsheet link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
={requisitions!A1:J1; FILTER(requisitions!A1:J900;
  NOT(COUNTIF(completed!A1:A900; requisitions!A1:A900)))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you very much. Just an additional question:
These spreadsheets will not have an exact number of rows, if I put the ranges of A1: A999999 for example, will it be able to perform poorly in the future? if not, no problem. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @user616324 take a look at: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795616/5632629**