# Filter Excel Sheet with two variables with multiple entries

Tags: google-docs

I have a form in Google Docs that I am wanting to use on a daily basis to keep track of sales.
The data from this would be collected in a "response" sheet.

There is two sets of data that I would like to use out of these responses to formulate a master scorecard for each rep.

For example:
Date on Master Scorecard is set to 8/25/13, the formula would look at the "response" and count for 8/25 for Braden each "smart" entry in the 3rd column.

Seems like it would be Index and a Count function but I can't seem to find the right way to get both criteria worked in there.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkqY19RIxDvmdDNGSUJLZDQ1RWJPMktUblJIZVVKcmc&usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: check out the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128987/sumifs-function-in-google-spreadsheet - this approach should also work in your case

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is C4

```
=counta(iferror(FILTER(Response!$B$2:$B$11,Response!$B$2:$B$11=$B4,Response!$A$2:$A$11=$B$2,Response!$C$2:$C$11=C$3),""))
```

Do a search in Google for explanation of Filter function, if required do let me know in case any help in required on understanding the formula....